# How to traverse in jQuery based header description?

Tags: jquery

following is code :

```
<table class="sortable doOddEven" id="queryResult">
        <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>Index</th>
                    <th>info1</th>
                    <th>info2</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                </tr>   
                <tr>
                    <th>1</th>
                    <td>1234</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>June 1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>2</th>
                    <td>1235</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>June 2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>3</th>
                    <td>1236</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                    <td>June 3</td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

My query is : How to traverse in jQuery based header description?

For the above code, I need to verify the value under "info2" header. if it is "3",  i need to print corresponding row's date.

Can you please help me out

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
// Get the table jquery object
var $table = $('#queryResult');

// Get the index of the column having 'info2' text
var index = $table.find("th:contains('info2')").index();

// Loop through all the table rows
$table.find('tr').each(function(){

    // Get the text of that column in each row
    var text = $(this).find('td:eq(' + (index -1) + ')').text();

    // if it is "3", alert corresponding row's date.
    if(text == '3')
        alert($(this).find('td:eq(' + index + ')').text());  // June 2
});
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/PUsTG/)